# visual studio fopen crashes

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012, visual-c++, c99

I have an application which opens the file in write mode using the standard fopen function

```
   fp = fopen(fName, "w");
    if (fp){
<some functions/print statements>
}
```

While debugging, it is quits/exits the application in the function CreateFileW() in open.c file (which is a part of inbuilt VC compiler). It does not hit the if condition in the code itself OR does not return any error code.

Comment: As far as I know MS compiler complains about fopen and other functions like this. According to Microsoft you should use fopen_s (_s stands for secure). Also you could try to hardcode the path to file to check if there is problem with fName variable.

Comment: Does `fName` have a proper terminator?

Comment: Is `fName` equal to `NULL`?

Comment: Can you provide a MCVE with which we can replicate the fault?

Comment: the value of fName is "F:\\PROJECT_FILES\\ATS_ROFP_APPS\\737_MDS_REHOST\\ENVIRONMENT\\APPS\\AOI\\b737mds.aoi\\exe\\L1_AOI_Part.nvram" - the file is similar to txt file though the extension if *.nvram

Comment: even if I use fopen_s, it quits at the same function. I tried hardcoding the path also, but no luck..

Comment: Two possibilities. 1) your program has undefined behavior prior to this point in the code. 2) there's some sort of permissions problem, or file system incompatibility at the given path. To check 1), put the `fopen` with a hardcoded path at the beginning of `main`. To check 2), try creating that file with a text editor.

Comment: Do you/your app have write access to that folder?

Comment: Yes, I have write access to that folder and the fopen() also creates the file in that directory, but after creating the file, it exits without any return from fopen()